# how to have total time difference in sql in other column

Tags: c#

I need some help I entered time difference values in my  database I need total hours in other column. I have two textbox which I entered time in those textbox and I got difference value in other textbox so I will take other textbox so I need total hours in that text box.

Comment: please show us an example

Comment: I didn't get u example of what

Comment: please show your code; it is often more clear than words. thank you.